# Android: Make default holo button opaque

Tags: java, android, android-layout, button, transparency

By default, the buttons in ICS are a little bit transparent.
I would like to accomplish that the button keeps all its properties (shape, color, state pressed), but than make it opaque.

How could I achieve that?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: you need to give your own background to button for this.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can create a style for the button extending the default style (if you are using Holo.Light):

```
<style name="GreenButton" parent="android:Widget.Holo.Button">
    <item name="android:background">#00ff00</item>
</style>
```

Then apply the style manually to the button with the style attribute or, if you want to change all buttons, set the buttonStyle in your app's theme:

```
<style name="AppTheme" parent="android:Theme.Holo">
    <item name="android:buttonStyle">@style/GreenButton</item>
</style>
```

Comment: This way I can make it opaque, but for some reason, this doesn't keep the holo style.

Comment: @Merlin When you are using plain holo, try removing the Light from both styles.

Answer (score 3):

You could also ut a view, with a solid background just under the button. Given that you have a relativ layout this would serve you well.

```
<View
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
    android:layout_alignTop="@+id/button"
    android:layout_alignLeft="@id/button"
    android:layout_alignBottom="@id/button"
    android:layout_alignRight="@id/button"
    android:background="@android:color/black"
    />
```

Comment: That's a good solution as well! This could come in pretty handy I think! Thanks